# VBA DisplayAlert not setting to false

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having an issue in excel VBA with application.displayalerts = false.

When I send this command line in my program the displayalerts properties don't change to false, it remains true. When I execute it in the immediate window it turns to false. I couldn't find anything related to that.

I've already checked for the EnableEvent properties as I found on another topic, it is enabled.

I'm not sure which part of my code I should post because I tried this command both where I want it, in the middle of my code and as the first line of code. Also, this is running on an excel file which has other modules, some of them have public functions (which shouldnt affect anything) and some have public variables that I pasted below. Other than that, this is a complete independent code that don't really on the other ones

```
Public pctCompl As Integer
Public statCol As Collection
Public session As NotesSession
Public db As NotesDatabase
Public lmt As Integer
```

The code I'm using for the display alert

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = false
```

Let me know what else info you guys need or code

EDIT:
here's the code. Right after the line is executed the displayalerts propertie is still set to true, so it's not the case of it being set to true in other part of the code, the line is not changing the propertie, which is very strange because it does change it when I execute it on the immediate window

```
Sub Main()

Dim Mwksh As Worksheet
Dim Metwksh As Worksheet
Dim Swksh As Worksheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False ''''''Dont work
'Set the worbooks
Set Mwksh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MASTER_SHT)
Set Swksh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SUPPORT_SHT)

'Open the Metrics workbook
Set Metwksh = OpenFile

'Find the Master File last column and row
clLast = LastCol(Mwksh, MASTER_HEADER_ROW)
rwLast = LastRow(Mwksh)

'Copy the content from the master file to the support sheet so it can be fixed before being copied to the metrics file
Swksh.UsedRange.ClearContents
Mwksh.Range(MASTER_FIRST_COL & MASTER_HEADER_ROW & ":" & clLast & rwLast).Offset(1, 0).Copy Destination:=Swksh.Range("A1")

DeleteColumns Swksh

InsertColumns Swksh

ClearDataSheet Metwksh

CopyToData Swksh, Metwksh

Metwksh.Parent.RefreshAll

Metwksh.Parent.Close savechanges:=True

MsgBox "Metrics file updated!"

End Sub
```

Comment: It's `DisplayAlerts` not `DisplayAlert`, and it resets when your code ends.

Comment: The S was a typo on my post, I wrote it as Application.DisplayAlerts on the code. sorry bout that =)

Comment: Then you should post the code that actually uses `Displayalerts` and indicate how you are testing that it is not in fact being set properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
Your code here
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

You forgot the s on end

If this does not solve the problem, use `[your instance name].DisplayAlerts` instead of `Application.DisplayAlerts`

Comment: The s was a typo in my post, i've edited it now. What you mean with instance name? How do I reference the current excel instance if it's not an instance that I explicitly created?